# where should we initialize ObjectBox Store with navigation 2.0 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

i'm building a flutter App using navigation 2.0
and i'm starting to use ObjectBox library to store user appdata.

for now i initialize it that way in my main.dart then import the variable objectBox whenever i want to use it in the viewModels.

```
late ObjectBox objectBox;
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
objectBox = await ObjectBox.init();
runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

i initialise it like that and put objectBox as a global variable ... but i think it's not good at all. what are the good practices around that?

MyApp is basically

```
MaterialApp.router(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  routeInformationParser: NavigationParser(),
  routerDelegate: NavigationDelegate(),
)
```

with the router ( NavigationDelegate() )  where i get to normally store global variables and initialise things i need in the app.

what would you advice me?

thanks,
Badr

Comment: i'm creating a singleton that i will create in the main and initialise it in the main. so that each time i call it, i already have acess to this _objectBox. what do you think of that?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is completely fine. Putting it as a global variable is a straightforward way to make sure you have access to ObjectBox through out your entire application. [ObjectBox examples](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/main/objectbox/example/flutter/objectbox_demo_sync/lib/main.dart#:%7E:text=///%20Provides%20access%20to,%7D) also used the same pattern.